# Ввод символов input?

Tags: vue.js

как запретить ввод символов в поле не больше 29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    max: 29,
    text: ''
  }
});
```

Пример можете посмотреть [Тут(Codepen)](https://codepen.io/CSWApps/pen/RQbvvp)

Comment: какой же ВЮ крут

Comment: :maxlength где взялось?

Comment: Не понял вопроса. Считается кол-во симоволов в поле input :maxlength="max". А потом просто выводится количество оставшееся кол-во символов через text.maxlength

Comment: это есть встроена деректива во ВЮ?

Comment: Да нет, это обычный параметр поля input. Именно он ограничивает количество символов, которые могут быть введены в поле. В данном случае туда просто передаётся параметр max, чтобы с ним можно было работать

Comment: спасибо а где об этом можно почитать (:maxlength)

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-input-maxlength-attribute/